# How to access cookies method in a Rails 3.0 metal class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I have a Rails 3.0 metal class that is in app/controllers directory.

```
class FooMetalController < ActionController::Metal

  include ActionController::Cookies
  include ActionController::Helpers::ClassMethods
  include ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore

  def hit
    unless cookies[:user_id].nil?
      logger.info("Cookies value is : #{cookies[:user_id]}")
      redirect_to "http://www.yahoo.com"
    else
      cookies[:user_id] = { :value => "198", :expires => 180.days.from_now }
      redirect_to "http://www.google.com"
    end
  end

end
```

When I hit the url with: `http://localhost:3000/foo`, the `hit` method gets called. The problem is that it is not able to use the cookies method. I have included modules related to cookies, still I am getting : ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `helper_method' for
error message.

How do I make a Rails metal class recognize the cookies method?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/cookies.rb

It looks like including `ActionController::Cookies` implicitly calls `helper_method` when it is included. Try including `ActionController::Helpers` before `ActionController::Cookies`.